# Why do the PV and FV formulas (in Excel, at least) use slightly different geometric series?

Tags: finance, discount

With geometric series, I understand that, broadly, you can sum from $1$ to $n$, or from $0$ to $n-1$.

Let $r=0.03, p=\\\$10, n = 10$.

| $\sum_{j=s}^{j=s+n-1}{pa^j}=\frac{p\left(a^{n}-1\right)a^s}{a-1}$ | $a=\left(1+r\right)$ | $a={\left(1+r\right)}^{-1}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $s=0$ | $\color{red}{\\\$114.64}$ | $\\\$87.86$ |
| $s=1$ | $\\\$118.08$ | $\color{red}{\\\$85.30}$ |

Now, in Excel, at least, I get:

$$\text{PV}\left(\text{rate}=r, \text{nper}=n,\text{pmt}=p,\text{fv}=0 \right)=-\\\$85.30$$
$$\text{FV}\left(\text{rate}=r, \text{nper}=n,\text{pmt}=-p,\text{pv}=0 \right)=\\\$114.64$$

So it looks like FV is a geometric sum from $j=0$ to $j=n-1$, whereas PV is a geometric sum from $j=1$ to $j=n$.

The final $\text{type}$ parameter of the formula can be used to adjust this result - but, again, PV() and FV() work in opposite ways.

| $f\left(r, n, \pm p, 0, t\right)$ | $f=\text{PV}$ | $f=\text{FV}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $t=0$ | $-\\\$85.30$ | $\\\$114.64$ |
| $t=1$ | $-\\\$87.86$ | $\\\$118.08$ |

Why is this? Why do the two formulas work "backwards" relative to each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you want to calculate the PV as of one period prior to the first cashflow (like a bond price).   Whereas, usually you want to calculate the FV coincident with the last cashflow (no economic purpose beyond that).  Does this explain it?